# how to start changing the existing cpu scheduling into group scheduling in linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, cpu, scheduling

Here's my understanding of the problem:

We are asked to **change the existing cpu scheduler**, which simply splits the cpu usage depending on *how many processes there are.* **it does not care about the groups.**

(I created 2 groups in terminal using "groupadd" and 3 users using "useradd".

then I used "usermod -G..." to add these users to the groups.

*group1:* user1, user2

*group2:* user3.

*user1 runs 2 processes*,

*user2 runs 1 process*,

*user3 runs 1 process*

When I use "top" command to see all processes running, I can see that they all use ~%25 of the cpu.)

but what I want to achieve is: (I believe it's called "group scheduling")

*group1 and group2 gets %50*

so,

user1's processes get %12,5 %12,5,

user2's process gets %25,

user3's process gets %50)

As a complete beginner (I only know how to make a system call, U know how to get a process' nice, counter... values), I have no idea how to start this.

linux/kernel/sched.c

linux/include/linux/sched.h

linux/kernel/fork.c

linux/include/asm-i386/param.h

I tried checking these files out but I don't even know what I'm looking for. I'm really lost here. Can you please give me a starting point? A tip about what to change or what and where to add?

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a debian system install

```
apt-get install cgroup-tools
```

The have a look at their man pages for details. The place to start as always is the man pages ie

```
man cgrules.conf
```

You can setup rules as follows (taken from man page)

```
Rules have two formats:

           <user>                   <controllers>       <destination>
           <user>:<process name>    <controllers>       <destination>
.....
.....
peter           cpu             test1/
%               memory          test2/
```

The man page has tons of information it it.